# Searching source of Malware in Chromium extensions

Tags: chromium, malware, chrome-extension

I installed chromium for Ubuntu. Last night when I opened it up I got some freaky malware thing, warning me to redirect myself somewhere. It occurred not long after I added some extensions from the chromium store, so I'm guessing it might have come with one of them. So I removed chromium. 
Knowing that I'm completely computer illiterate, (so please go easy on me),;
If I reinstall chromium again,will all the add ons still be there? ie the apps and extensions?
If so,should I just delete them all, or are there steps I should/could take to see if there is a bug in them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they will be there because you only removed the application however your profile and all of its data still lives on your Ubuntu.

You have to remove your profiles:

```
mv ~/.config/chromium ~/.config/chromium.removed
```

then reinstall it, you should be fine now, do not forget if your Google sync was enabled, enabling it again brings the extension and its malicious configs back to your browser.

If that's the case then follow [these instructions](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6386691?hl=en):

> To stop syncing and clear your synced data or reset a sync passphrase, follow these steps:
>
> Open your Google Dashboard. Make sure you are signed in to your Google Account.
>       Click Reset sync to stop syncing and clear all of your synced data.
>       Click OK.
>
> Note: You only need to do this once. It will stop sync on all of your devices and remove your synced data from your Google Account.

Comment: So it's safer to not ever enable Google sync?

Comment: Depends on what you are doing and what kind stuff you're going to install on your browser... start using it without the sync for a while after you was sure that nothing is wrong with your stuff enable it... that's my call.

Answer (score 0):

Google Sync is okay to have enabled. one of the better ways to setup your sync is to use your OWN password versus having it accessable online through your (hypothetically) compromised email account. Suggestion... if you do this option, do not make your password the same password you use for your email... (which i am sure many of you will do anyways)

When you sign into your account on a new device, it will ask you if you would like to manage you account and sync upon signing in. You dont have to. If you have... You can remove the offending app from your account. and proceed to do so also on every other device you are using that is with sync enabled. (Just to be safe) then, it  is also not a bad idea to do a search for the files on your computer and eliminate it there as well.